# Get value of current and previous date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables, Store and LigneProduct :

```
--------------       ------------
LigneProduct          Store
--------------       ------------
L_Date               S_CodeStore
L_CodeStore          S_Libelle
L_Rayon
L_Sales
```

I'v create a procedure with start and end date to get the Total Sales by Rayon for the entered date and date -1 (years -1)

```
Alter [Sales] @StartDate nvarchar(30),@EndDate nvarchar(30)
AS

DECLARE @StartDatePreviousYear DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @StartDate)
DECLARE @EndDatePreviousYear DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @EndDate)

BEGIN

SELECT 

[STORE] = ET1.S_LIBELLE,

[RAYON] = L_Rayon,

[SALES] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,0),SUM(CASE WHEN
[L_Date ] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate THEN ISNULL([L_Sales], 0) ELSE 0 END)),

[SALES Y-1]= CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,0),SUM(CASE WHEN [L_Date ] BETWEEN @StartDatePreviousYear AND @EndDatePreviousYear THEN ISNULL([L_Sales], 0) ELSE 0 END)) AS [Sales Y-1]

FROM LigneProduct

LEFT OUTER JOIN Store ET1 ON L_CodeStore =ET1.S_CodeStore

WHERE

L_CodeStore NOT IN ('001','H10','B30') 

GROUP BY
ET1.S_LIBELLE, L_Rayon

END
GO

EXEC [dbo].[Sales] @StartDate = '2019-11-01' ,@EndDate = '2019-11-01'
```

Ther's something wrong in my query that i don't know. The query it's executed with no error message but no result excepted after more then 10 min ..

Expected result :

```
-----  ------  -----  ----------
Store  Rayon   Sales  Sales Y-1
-----  -----   ------ ----------
S01    R01     1528   1650
S01    R02      550    780
S02    R02     658    666
S02    R03      654   80
..
```

Comment: what is ``ET_ETABLISSEMENT `` in where??

Comment: How long does the query take when you run it in SSMS?

Comment: Your query will likely scan your tables due to the very few rows eliminated by the where clause. At a minimum you want filter for rows within the 2 periods. In addition, your left join is HIGHLY suspicious - as in backwards. Lastly - choose the correct datatypes. Your parameters should be defined as date, not nvarchar.

Comment: And learn to format your code. That wall of text is difficult to read. White space and indentation help everyone - including you - read and understand your code. Randomly adding blank lines everywhere does not help.

Comment: What's the count with that 1 criteria? `select count(*) from LigneProduct where L_CodeStore NOT IN ('001','H10','B30')`  Is it 0?